# Where did the "recently added" go in Google Chrome's bookmarks manager?

Tags: google-chrome, bookmarks

Where did the "recently added" go in Google Chrome's bookmarks manager? Although I see extensions that will display the recently added bookmarks on the Chrome Web Store and tried some, they wreak havoc with my other extensions. I want the Bookmarks Manager's own "recently added" function back.  Is it gone for good?

Comment: Which version of Chrome did you update to and what was the last one you had that did have it?

Comment: I have 32.0.1700.72 m. I don't remember which was the last one that did have the "recently added", because I haven't checked the "recently added" in a while. It may have been several iterations back that did have it.

Comment: Ok, well, it exists in 27.0.1453.110 at chrome://bookmarks/#recent

Comment: Exactly. It has gone AWOL since, somewhere between 27 and 32, I guess.